# How to move data from one Elasticsearch index to another using the Bulk API

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new to Elasticsearch. How to move data from one Elasticsearch index to another using the Bulk API?

Comment: Hello, please elaborate on your question and let us know what you have tried so far. That way we can be more informed to help you in your situation

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using [Logstash](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/index.html) for this, i.e. you use one [`elasticsearch` input](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-elasticsearch.html) plugin to retrieve the data from your index and another [`elasticsearch` output](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html) plugin to push the data to your other index.

The config logstash config file would look like this:

```
input {
  elasticsearch {
   hosts => "localhost:9200"
   index => "source_index"           <--- the name of your source index
  }
}
filter {
 mutate {
  remove_field => [ "@version", "@timestamp" ]
 }
}
output {
 elasticsearch {
   host => "localhost"
   port => 9200
   protocol => "http"
   manage_template => false
   index => "target_index"           <---- the name of your target index
   document_type => "your_doc_type"  <---- make sure to set the appropriate type
   document_id => "%{id}"
   workers => 5
 }
}
```

After [installing Logstash](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/getting-started-with-logstash.html), you can run it like this:

```
bin/logstash -f logstash.conf
```

Comment: Thank for your replay Valentin, is this possible without logstash and using only Bulk API in Elasticsearch.

Comment: Yes, basically by re-implementing what logstash does :-) There are plenty of examples available, one of which is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26371237/reindexing-elastic-search-via-bulk-api-scan-and-scroll). If you're using Python, you can use the [`reindex` helper](http://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.org/en/latest/helpers.html#elasticsearch.helpers.reindex).